# Would a "validate" button be beneficial for the site?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers, accepted-answer

While I am aware that there is obviously the voting system for questions and answers across all the stack exchange sites, I thought having a sort of "validate" button or feature as a sort of *"I've tried this and can vouch for its ability to solve this problem"*.

Let me go into some more detail, with this kind of site you are going to get a lot of crazy solutions to some problems which sometimes can seem ingenious and other times can seem a little far fetched and you aren't sure whether to believe it or not. A button or feature that would allow fellow users (above a certain rep no doubt) to vouch for the method in order to give this site a little bit more trustworthiness and make it the reliable source for people to visit in order to get hacks that they can trust will work for a given problem.

Not only would it help other users it would even more greatly benefit the original poster of the question as they could get other people's experience before trying it out themselves. Even as a further feature or alternative feature there could be a button or something for the asker which could say *"I attempted this method and it worked wonders for me"* or something along those lines.

I know this could be done by simply adding a comment but I personally feel that a more stand out feature on the answers that would just make it that must easier and clearer for someone not familiar with the site to be able to understand!

Now go easy on me with this idea as it is 2:30am and we all know from How I Met Your Mother that nothing good ever happens after 2am, but I genuinely think this could add something a little different from the current life hack sites out there as well as making it better and more appealing.

I have also thought about a "de-bunk" feature to go along with it but am less confident of this half of the whole idea as it could lead to petty arguments and such things so I haven't thought as much about that part but would be the same concept just the other way around to the "validate" feature.

Just a quick note... I am not actually sure if what I am asking is possible or something that is meant for the meta site but I believe I have seen feature requests before - maybe not quite of this magnitude as it would add something quite big to the site but thought I would sort of bring it to the table and see what other people thought of the idea or if I am just plain crazy.

This is a feature request as well as a discussion to see what other peple think, if it's a good idea and can be improved, or if it's terrible and should never be brought up again. I might not have explained the idea in the best way so before discarding the idea, ask if anything is unclear and I'll edit it or you can if you feel you can make it that bit better.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: How would “validate” be different from “upvote”? How would you know that the person “validating” has genuinely done the experiment?

Comment: @Gilles well you wouldn't really you'd just hope that people would use the up vote feature for "that sounds like a good answer, they've put some thought into it and is pretty hacky" as opposed to a validate which would be as I've stated "yes this works" but I get that there's not way of really moderating it

Answer (score 5):

I don't think this would be good. As you mentioned in the comment above, people might upvote just because an answer sounds good, and a lot of times that is the case. But if someone thinks that an answer sounds far fetched, but works, they can just comment. Also, if we did have a "validate" button people would probably use that the same as they would use an upvote. To me, it seems like a pointless feature.